# Unix scripting variable display

Tags: unix

I a writing a script that will pull data from several files and display them into a single output.

This is the data4 data:

```
Performance Data
F gge0006x gge0006y gge0006z
D 12-30-2006 12-30-2006 12-30-2006
T 14:05:23 14:05:55 14:06:28
S a69 a69 a69
B 15.4 15.3 15.7
M gge06001 gge06001 gge06001
P 30.8 30.6 30.3
Q 19.2 21.1 23.5
R 1006.2 1006.6 1008
U 1012.7 1014.6 1014.1
X 36.2 36.1 36.6
A 38.994 38.994 38.994
G 107.71 107.71 107.71
H 8.411 8.433 8.434
O 37.084 36.705 36.508
C 7.537 7.621 7.546
K 28.198 27.623 27.574
W 212.52 210.51 208.08
L 68.1 68 67.6
```

Here is my script so far

```
echo "Performance Data"

data1=`head -n19 L2E1.iva | tr -s " " | awk '{ print $1,$2}' | awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }' `
data2=`head -n19 L2E2.iva | tr -s " " | awk '{ print $2}' | awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }' `
data3=`head -n19 L2E3.iva | tr -s " " | awk '{ print $2}' | awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }' `
data4=`paste -d' ' <(echo "$data1") <(echo "$data2") <(echo "$data3")`


echo "Curve Name" "$data4" | grep "F" | awk '{ print $1, $2, $4, $5, $6 }'

echo "Date" "$data4" | grep "D" | awk '{ print $1, $3, $4, $5 }'
```

Everythign in the script is working fine except the line where I am to display the date. This is what my output is

```
Performance Data
Curve Name gge0006x gge0006y gge0006z
Date gge0006x gge0006y gge0006z
D 12-30-2006 12-30-2006
```

The output should be

```
Performance Data
Curve Name gge0006x gge0006y gge0006z
Date 12-30-2006 12-30-2006 12-30-2006
```

For some reason it is writing the same data in from the first command on Curve Name and putting that in for my Date line. It is then running the date command as if the echo "Date" was not even there. There must be some formatting that I am missing here. 
Any help would be great. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch, that is a really painful way to extract a header and the date stamps to the columns.

Why not preprocess your files with `dos2unix *.iva` and then

```
awk 'BEGIN{ print "Performance Data" }
     /^F/{$1=""; print "Curve Name" $0}
     /^D/{$1=""; print "Date" $0}' *.iva
```

As it is unclear from your sample data where the boundaries for the 3 files your process are, this is close as I can make it. Also unclear why you're not processing that actual data in the file. Your example output is just the date values.

If you expect to be processing this sort of data regularly, then spend time with the `awk` tutorial at http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html . If you want to really pursue it, get `Effective Awk Programming` (the latest edition). Also available as a pdf from the "GNU" source at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf.

IHTH

Comment: I read that link you provided and it has help a lot, thank you very much. The code snipped you provided does seem like it would to the trick, except for one thing.  I wanted to format these three files to unix format and squeeze the spaces out so that I can have all rows lined up evenly to extract the data more uniformly. So I put the properly formatted data into a new variable data4. Is there anyway to use the code you gave and have it reference the variable instead of a file as to have everything take place within this script

Comment: Your requirement to "squeeze the spaces out so that I can have all rows lined up evenly" seems contradictory to me. Either you want `fld1 fld2 fld3...` (one space between fields) or you want `fld1       fld2   fld3` where fld1 has a a wider data set than others. I'd recommend re-reading section in awk about `FS` and `OFS` variables (Output Field Seperator), and use the `|` char as like `OFS="|"` in the `BEGIN` section. ELSE you need to improve your required example output to show what  you mean. Good luck.

Comment: Will do. Thank you